# Increasing Cache Line and Programs with bad Spatial Locality

Tags: memory-management, cpu-cache, memory-hardware

I'm reading on caches and I'm feeling a bit lost with spatial locality.

From my understanding, increasing the cache line with a program that has high spatial locality reduces the miss rate.

But for a program that has low spatial locality, does an increase in cache line have any effect on the miss rate?

Comment: What do you mean by "increase in cache line"?  Do you mean increase the size of a cache line?

Answer (score 1):

There will be minimal, to no effect on the miss rate of a program with low spatial locality.

Comment: We prefer detailed answers that back up their reasoning with evidence, arguments, or analysis.  See http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer.  Can you edit your answer to provide the justification behind this statement?

Answer (score 0):

> From my understanding, increasing the cache line with a program that
>   has high spatial locality reduces the miss rate.

This is correct. Think of a dot product of two vectors, both with 16 values. Assume a cache line of 8 words. Now, on the first try, neither of the values from any vector will be in the cache. This will cause two read misses (one per vector) and require the first 8 values of each vector to be loaded into the cache. Now the ALU goes through and multiplies and accumulates 8 words. On trying to read the 9th words, it will incur a miss again (cache line size was 8) and will repeat the process.
OTOH, if the line size was 16 words, both vectors in their entirety would have been read in on the first set of misses.

> But for a program that has low spatial locality, does an increase in
>   cache line have any effect on the miss rate?

Now think of two matrices that are 1024x1024 and have to be multiplied up. If you do it the way I was taught in high school, you'd have high spatial locality on the first matrix (since you are reading it row-wise) but **low** spatial locality on the second one (since you have to read the first column). Now, how do the number of read misses incurred because of the low spatial locality of this column-wise read change with a cache line of 8? 16? 32?